# Wordpress problem, fail to open stream in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm getting this weird message while trying to enter some of the pages of my WordPress.

> Warning: require_once(/home3/alexismoyano/calendario/calendario/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/includes/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/alexismoyano/calendario/calendario/wp-content/themes/Avada/functions.php on line 51
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home3/alexismoyano/calendario/calendario/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/includes/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php70/lib/php') in /home3/alexismoyano/calendario/calendario/wp-content/themes/Avada/functions.php on line 51

I don't understand what could it be, it seems to be related to the theme "Twentnineteen" despite I'm not even using it.

This is what it's on LINE 51:

```
This is what it says on line 51:
```

LINE 51 : " require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/bootstrap.php'; "

```
/**
 * Check that the site meets the minimum requirements for the theme before proceeding.
 * @since 6.0
 */
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], AVADA_MIN_WP_VER_REQUIRED, '<' ) || version_compare( PHP_VERSION, AVADA_MIN_PHP_VER_REQUIRED, '<' ) ) {
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/bootstrap-compat.php';
    return;
}

/**
 * Bootstrap the theme.
 *
 * @since 6.0
 */
require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/bootstrap.php';
```

Does someone know how can I solve it?

Comment: The issue is on your `/themes/Avada/functions.php` on line 51. A function that's there is referencing the file in the twentyninteen theme on that line. You'll need to post the code around there to see what's going on

Comment: This is what it says on line 51:
LINE 51 : " require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/bootstrap.php'; "


/**
 * Check that the site meets the minimum requirements for the theme before proceeding.
 * since 6.0
 */
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], AVADA_MIN_WP_VER_REQUIRED, '<' ) || version_compare( PHP_VERSION, AVADA_MIN_PHP_VER_REQUIRED, '<' ) ) {
 require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/bootstrap-compat.php';
 return;
}

/**
 * Bootstrap the theme.
 *
 * since 6.0
 */
require_once get_template_directory() . '/includes/bootstrap.php';

Comment: I edited the original question so that it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it looks like the `twentynineteen` theme is set as a template theme, and Avada is set as a child theme.

The function [`get_template_directory()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/) is identical to [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/) **except** for the fact it looks at the Template/Parent theme first instead of the current (child) theme.

Take a look at the documentation for [Child Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). You'll notice there's a comment block at the top of the `style.css` file that determines the parent/template theme, as an example:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Some Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentynineteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
```

You see in line in there `Template: twentynineteen`, that's telling your active theme to use that as a parent theme.

Now, I'm not familiar with Avada, but is it *supposed* to be a child theme of Twentynineteen? I don't believe so, but if it *is*, try reinstalling the twentynineteen theme. If it's not supposed to be, then make sure you don't have a `Template: twentynineteen` line in your `style.css` file.

If neither of those things work, you could also try replacing the `get_template_{…}()` functions with `get_stylesheet_{…}()` functions, but those would get reverted if/when you updated the theme.